# Sending values between Windows forms

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio

I'm working on a project where I want to send values between forms, however I ran into a problem.

Form 1:

```
public Vägval(string name, string gender, int gold)
        {
            
           
            InitializeComponent();
            ChoosePicture(gender);
            tname.Text = name;
            string Namn = name;
            string Gender = gender;
            int Gold = gold;
            tMynt.Text = gold.ToString();
            tLife.Text = 5.ToString();
            Skattkista skatt = new Skattkista(Namn, Gender, Gold);


        }
```

When picture is clicked I wanna open the second Form and send three values with it: Name, Gender and gold.

```
 private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Skattkista skatt = new Skattkista(Namn, Gender, Gold);
            skatt.Show();
        }
```

But I get error here:

> The name 'Namn' does not exist in the current context
>
> The name 'Gender' does not exist in the current context
>
> The name 'Gold'does not exist in the current context

I tried putting the `Skattkista skatt = new Skattkista(Namn, Gender, Gold);`on the constructor but then I cant open the form when the picture is clicked.

All I want is to open a new form and send three values with it when the picture is clicked

Comment: I'm just gonna mention that wanna is not actually an English word...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though your variables might have a local scope to the method you created them in and not a global scope to the form itself. I cannot tell without more code. One suggestion would be to try giving each form global properties

```
public string Namn {get; set;}
public string Gender {get; set;}
public int Gold {get; set;}
```

Your Constructor should then look like this

```
public Vägval(string name, string gender, int gold)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ChoosePicture(gender);

        //assigns all the properties
        this.Namn = name;
        this.Gender = gender;
        this.Gold = gold;

        //Set GUI 
        tname.Text = name;
        tMynt.Text = gold.ToString();
        tLife.Text = 5.ToString();
    }
```

The Click Event

```
 private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Create new form object using Vagval properties and show it
        Skattkista skatt = new Skattkista(this.Namn, this.Gender, this.Gold);
        skatt.Show();
    }
```

Comment: Where am I supposed to put those public properties?

Comment: put them at the top of the form right after the public partial class declaration

Comment: Ohh sorry, you spelled Public with a captial P, thats why it didnt work. Thanks alot!

Comment: You can also put them at the bottom just make sure they are inside the second to last bracket

Comment: no problem just make sure to mark this as the answer and up vote

Comment: I need one more point to be able to vote up. If you vote up my question, I will vote up your answer.